# Show BottomNavigation once the user is logged

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I want to use `BottomNavigation` to navigation between screens actually its working fine with `BottomNavigation.SceneMap({...})`

but the `BottomNavigation` its being showing in every screens, i only want to show once the user is logged. after click on login button

```
import React from 'react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import userReducer from './src/reducers/user'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { BottomNavigation, Text } from 'react-native-paper'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { theme } from './src/core/theme'
import {
  StartScreen,
  Dashboard,
  GroupScreen,
  InviteScreen,
  CreateGroup,
} from './src/screens'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()
const store = createStore(userReducer)
export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0)
  const [routes] = React.useState([
    { key: 'music', title: 'Music', icon: 'queue-music' },
    { key: 'albums', title: 'Albums', icon: 'album' },
  ])

  const one = () => (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator
        initialRouteName="StartScreen"
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="StartScreen" component={StartScreen} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} /> 
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )

  const two = () => (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="InviteScreen" component={InviteScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )

  const renderScene = BottomNavigation.SceneMap({
    music: one,
    albums: two,
  })

  return (
    <Provider store={store} theme={theme}>
      <BottomNavigation
        navigationState={{ index, routes }}
        onIndexChange={setIndex}
        renderScene={renderScene}
      />
    </Provider>
  )
}
```

EDIT by answers:

i did this when i pressed the button login i need to redirect to dashboard but dashboard is in mytabs

```
function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      
    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}
```

does not render nothing, i just to copy any example from here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/ any of those render in my local, i am using EXPO

for example this

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyTabs />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

[image]

the wrong is `display:none`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your BottomNavigation in another stack that has loginScreen side by side.

Try using createBottomTabNavigator

```
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
```

```
<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="loginScreen">
    <Stack.Screen name="loginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="main" component={MyTabs} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Comment: i am getting this error Module not found: Can't resolve '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs' in '/myapp/native/front/react-native-login-template'

Comment: Did you add the package with `yarn add @react-navigation/bottom-tabs` command?

Comment: your answer is deleting BottomNavigation,  BottomNavigation.SceneMap(, additionally with your answer does not render nothing see i post a picture

Comment: When you are trying to reset the route you should specify the screens step by step
From what I can see in your Edit you need to add a nested screen in the reset action
add `initialRouteName="Dashboard"` to MyTabs (Tab.Navigator)
and then in reset action try this: `{"index":0,"routes":[{"name":"main"}]}`

Comment: Also, you are using react-native-paper with BottomNavigation, I suggest to use react navigation bottom tabs

Comment: but still i can not see my dashboard screen, does not any wrong now only the render is white screen like the picture in my question  i am using EXPO

Comment: does not render nothing, i just to copy any example from here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/ any of those render in my local, i am using EXPO

Comment: Try to add different background color to all stack options and screens, then you can find which one is rendering and which one is not rendering. 
Maybe this way you can find the problem.
Then share more details and if I could, I will try to help

Comment: i edited my question see please, i put a gif, the wrong is display:none

Comment: As what I can see in your edits, You didn't add
```<NavigationContainer>
  <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="loginScreen">
    <Stack.Screen name="loginScreen" component={LoginScreen} />
    <Stack.Screen name="main" component={MyTabs} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>```
Put MyTabs in another stack navigator alongside the login screen (And make sure Login screen is initialScreen)

Answer (score 1):

Take what you already have with MyTabs() and create a LoginScreen and then do the following. You will need to detect whether the user is present. If there is a user, then show the main screen, if not show the login screen.

```
<>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
        {user ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={MainStack} />
        ) : (
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginStack} />
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do like this:

```
<NavigationContainer>
      {user !== null ? <RootNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
</NavigationContainer>
```

The user is a useState.
The NavigationContainer has 2 options. If the user is logged it shows the RootNAvigator with the bottomNavigation, if not it shows the authentication flow.